# How to compare length of String in Swift 4.0?

Tags: swift, string, swift4

In Swift 3, the length of a String could used as such `if str.characters?.count >= 2`.

In Swift 4, the `characters.count` method is deprecated. One should use only `count`.

However, when comparing `if str.count >= 2`, I get the following error:

> Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.IndexDistance?' (aka 'Optional') and 'Int'

How can I then make the comparison `if str.count >= 2`?

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with Swift 3 or 4. Your issue is that `str` is optional.

Comment: use `if str.count ?? 0 >= 2` instead

Comment: `let optionalCount = optionalString.map{ $0.count }`

Answer (score 4):

It's correct that in Swift 4 you can check the count by `.count` without accessing the `.characters`, however, the issue that it seems that the string is *optional*, so what you could do is to *optional binding* it:

```
if let string = str {
     if string.count > 2 // works fine here...
} else {
    // the string is nil...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

i think you might looking for something like this:

```
if let charsize =  str.count as? Int
{
    if (charsize > 3)
    {
        print(charsize)
    }
}
```